# WrapPanel not filling out to full required width

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I am trying to create a dynamic table in WPF based off an ItemsControl. Ideally I want each element of the collection rendered with a specific style and to fit 3 across the table before it wraps and goes to the next row. It works NEARLY perfectly, the only problem is I have a width of about 30 pixels empty space after entry 3 in the list. If you add up the numbers you will see that the textblocks + margin are equal to 140 each, so 3 of those is 420 - the table width is 450, so there is the problem you would think.

Sadly not.

If I increase the first text block to width of 110 instead of 105, just a small change, which would give a total width for 3 entries of 435, still less than 450 - which is the width of the table, then it wraps after only 2 entries and leaves a large empty space on the right.

My suspicion is that it might be due to "reserved space" that WPF holds for a vertical scrollbar, as that is usually 20 wide, which would give my usable space as 430, and 435 is higher than that, so it wraps.

My question is, how can I hide all scrollbars and make them not display at all or hold any reserved space, so that I can use the full width of the items control?

XAML below

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TradeCategories}" Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="450"  Background="{StaticResource SubTableRow}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="150">
                <TextBlock Width="105" FontSize="10" Text="{Binding CategoryName}" Foreground="{StaticResource SubTableText}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock Width="25" FontSize="10" Text="{Binding CategoryCount}" TextAlignment="Center" Background="{StaticResource SubTableHighlightCell}" Foreground="{StaticResource SubTableText}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: The default ItemsControl template doesn't have a `ScrollViewer`. Unless you override that yourself, it should not contain any scrollbars.

Comment: Can you see any scroll bars? I'm pretty sure that the `ItemsControl` doesn't have any... a `ListBox` does have an internal `ScrollViewer`, but an `ItemsControl` doesn't.

Comment: Hmm ok it's not that then. But back to my original problem I can't seem to fill more than 420 width of the above table. The wrap panel has MaxWidth 450 so should fit 3 items of width 150. But if the items have a width of more than 140 then only two display per row and the rest wrap, so the wrap panel is not being fully utilised

Comment: In your XAML, there is no `Margin` on the second `TextBlock`, so the total is 135, not 140.

Comment: If you're now asking a different question, you'd better change the title of your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the width of the `ItemControl` is smaller than you expect, it may be restricted by it's container.

An easy fix is to replace

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="450" ...
```

by

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MinWidth="450" ...
```

So as to be sure that the `WrapPanel` has enough room for 3 items.
That way, even if the `ItemControl` is smaller than 450, you'll still have 3 items per row.

Another solution is to force the `Width` of the `ItemControl` to be 450.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've ended up doing, setting the Width itself. Strangely to get the items to fully fill the contents of the table, I have to set the wrappanel width to 450 and the stackpanel items to 139 each, which means that times by 3 is 417. Very odd, so somewhere there is extra space being added but I don't know where. It is working now so I can close this issue off but I would like to still understand why this is happening

Comment: Are you sure that there is not a `Style` which modifies the `Width`, the `Margin` or the `Padding` of any of these controls ? You can easily check with Snoop (snoopwpf.codeplex.com).